# Why doesn't my nine-step path Cypher query on a small database ever finish?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are evaluating Neo4J for our application, testing it against a small test database with a total of around 20K nodes, 150K properties, and 100K relationships. The branching factor is ~100 relationships/node. Server and version information is below [1]. The Cypher query is:

```
MATCH p = ()-[r1:RATES]-(m1:Movie)-[r2:RATES]-(u1:User)-[r3:RATES]-(m2:Movie)-[r4:RATES]-()
RETURN r1.id as i_id, m1.id, r2.id, u1.id, r3.id, m2.id, r4.id as t_id;
```

(The first and last empty nodes aren't important to us, but I didn't see how to start with relationships.)

I killed it after a couple of hours. Maybe I'm expecting too much by hoping Neo4J would avoid combinatorial explosion. I tried tweaking some server parameters but got no further.

My main question is whether what I'm trying to do (a nine-step path query) is reasonable for Neo4J, or, for that matter, any graph database. I realize nine steps is a very deep search, and one that touches every node in the database multiple times, but unfortunately that's what our research needs to do.

Looking forward to your thoughts.

[1] System info:

- The Linux server has 32 processors and 64GB of memory.
- Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel (neo4j-kernel), version: 2.1.2.
- java version "1.7.0_60", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

Answer (score 3):

To answer your main question, Neo4j has no problem doing a variable length query that does not result in a combinatorial explosion in the search space (an exponential time complexity as a result of your branching factor).

There is however an optimization that can be done to your Cypher query.

```
MATCH ()-[r1:RATES]->(m1:Movie), 
      (m1)<-[r2:RATES]-(u1:User),
      (u1)-[r3:RATES]->(m2:Movie),
      (m2)<-[r4:RATES]-()
RETURN r1.id as i_id, m1.id, r2.id, u1.id, r3.id, m2.id, r4.id as t_id;
```

That being said, Cypher has some current limitations with these kinds of queries. We call these queries "graph global operations". When you are running a query that touches the graph globally without a specific starting point, computation as well as writes and reads to disc can cause performance bottlenecks. When returning large payloads over HTTP REST, you'll encounter data transfer limitations within your network.

To test the difference between query response times due to network data transfer constraints, compare the previous query to the following:

```
MATCH ()-[r1:RATES]->(m1:Movie), 
      (m1)<-[r2:RATES]-(u1:User),
      (u1)-[r3:RATES]->(m2:Movie),
      (m2)<-[r4:RATES]-()
RETURN count(*)
```

The difference between the queries in response time should be significant.

So what are your options?

Option 1:

Write a Neo4j unmanaged extension in Java that runs on-heap embedded in the JVM using Neo4j's Java API. Your Cypher query can be  translated imperatively into a traversal description that operates on your graph in-memory. Seeing that you have 64GB of memory, your Java heap should be configured so that Neo4j has access to 70-85% of your available memory.

You can learn more about the Neo4j Java API here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html

Option 2:

Tune the performance configurations of Neo4j to run your graph in-memory and optimize your Cypher queries to limit the amount of data transferred over the network. Performance will still be sub-optimal for graph global operations.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, Kenny. Re: "When returning large payloads over HTTP REST": Do you mean the query might have completed, but is spending its time returning results? Re: "variable length query": Mine is fixed length, so I don't follow. Re: your optimization: Is it the adding of directionality that's faster, or the separating of components by commas? I'll give the rest of your answer more thought.

Comment: Sure, hopefully it helps. If you're streaming results over HTTP there are timeout considerations. Your original query was using a pattern that has no starting point. The way Neo4j executes Cypher queries relates back to set theory. You query in a cascade, where you filter each set based on a pattern. My optimized query breaks this out into 4 triples, at each step the original set is reduced further. In the future it will do this for you. Specifying a direction is good practice, but the performance comes from the commas in MATCH.

Comment: I ran a simpler version of the query that has seven steps: ()-[r1:RATES]-(m1:Movie)-[r2:RATES]-(u1:User)-[r3:RATES]-() . Returning count(*) executed in 22 minutes, but the id version hasn't yet finished after three hours. Interesting, though the count isn't directly useful. I'll keep investigating...